# How to store user Uid in our Firebase Database on Android?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

i want to save/show current Login user Uid into the Firebase Database. This is my Code :

```
private EditText mEmail, mPassword;
private Button mLogin, mRegistration;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener firebaseAuthListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_driver_login);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    firebaseAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

            if (user!=null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(DriverLoginActivity.this,DriverMapActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return;
            }
        }
    };

    mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    mLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    mRegistration = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registration);


    mRegistration.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = mPassword.getText().toString();

           mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(DriverLoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
               @Override
               public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                   if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                       Toast.makeText(DriverLoginActivity.this,"sign up error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                   } else {

                       String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                       DatabaseReference current_user_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Drivers").child(user_id);
                       current_user_db.setValue(true);

                   }

               }
           });

        }
    });


    mLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
            final String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(DriverLoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(DriverLoginActivity.this,"sign in error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            });

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListener);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListener);

}
```

user registeration and user login module work properly but user Uid not save/show in firebase database.

basically i want to create app like uber and follow youtube turorial and link given below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5uDNNJyKehM&list=PLxabZQCAe5fgXx8cn2iKOtt0VFJrf5bOd&index=4

In this video  everything work properly but my Uid not display in database.

[This is my currently Login users screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqJad.jpg)

[And Here is firebase database after login user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLKBK.jpg)

Comment: is your Drivers node being created? Because your database structure image does not reflect your last query at createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Comment: i'm trying this with Riders Node also but its also not working. and above code is same like the tutorial,  link which given above.

Answer (score 0):

Default database rules in firebase is as follows.
These rules don't allow anyone read or write access to your database

```
 {
      "rules": {
        ".read": false,
        ".write": false
      }
    }
```

You have to change database rule  as following to allow authenticated user to read and write.

```
 {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth!=null",
    ".write": "auth!=null"
  }
}
```

please go to your firebase console and checkout the database rule tab of Database